# How to modify data of one column based on data present in another column of same row using pandas

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, list, pandas

I have 5x6 arrays.

The data are like below

```
indx    sv-01   sv-02   status-1   status-2  valu-1   valu-2
 0       8       16       B          B        0.1      -0.02
 1       8       16       B          A        0.03     0.210
 2       8       16       A          B        0.23     0.34
 3       8       16       B          B        0.29     0.67
 4       8       16       A          A        0.23     0.67
 ..      ..      ..       ..         ..       ...      ...
```

My aim is to do iteration such that either for SV 8 or 16 if status column is 
A ,convert its corresponding value to 0(I need it for further calculation). I have some homegrown ways but could 
not get make it to desire result. How can I achieve this with minimum for and
if condition.Is it possible throw pandas dataframe. And also whenever there
is A then that SV will not be counted ,so total sv would be based on B only.
At this moment I got confused with too many if and else conditions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `df.where` i.e

```
df['valu-1'] = df['valu-1'].where(df['status-1']!='A',0)
df['valu-2'] = df['valu-2'].where(df['status-2']!='A',0)
```

Output :

```
    indx  sv-01  sv-02 status-1 status-2  valu-1  valu-2
0     0      8     16        B        B    0.10   -0.02
1     1      8     16        B        A    0.03    0.00
2     2      8     16        A        B    0.00    0.34
3     3      8     16        B        B    0.29    0.67
4     4      8     16        A        A    0.00    0.00
```

For selecting the df sv-01 and sv-02 be to 8 and 16 you can use boolean indexing like

```
ndf = df[(df['sv-01']==8) & (df['sv-02']==16)]
```

Then use `ndf.where` for replacement

Comment: @ Bharath . Thanks